# Simple question about compared Map (/@) against Apply first level (@@@)

Tags: functions, headers-footers

Does the function Map (/@)  is equivalent to Apply to first level (@@@) ?

he way that I see this head functions are that both are equivalent. Please, comment if they have a fundamental difference.

Comment: Compare `f /@ g[h[1], h[2], h[3]]` and `f @@@ g[h[1], h[2], h[3]]` to see the difference :) Remember, `Map` wraps functions around stuff, while `Apply` replaces the heads of stuff.

Comment: Map creates functions that takes a list as argument, Apply at first level creates functions that take multiple arguments.

Comment: Well, try it: `f @@@ {{1,2},{x,y}}` and `f /@ {{1,2}, {x,y}}`.  Is the result the same or different?  Remember that it's not necessary to define `f` to do this (in fact you shouldn't define it to really see what's happening).

Comment: `f /@ list` maps a function `f` onto each element of `list`, so `list` is a set of arguments on which `f` will be evaluated. `f @@@ list` replaces the `Head` of each level-1 element in `list`.

Comment: You might be interested in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141166/in-mathematica-what-does-mean) by [dreeves](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4234/dreeves) who points out that we may think of `f@@@lst` as being a shorthand for `f @@ # & /@ lst`.  That is, we may think of  Apply at level one as being equivalent to mapping Apply to each (level one) element of lst. Perhaps this is what you mean? `f @@ # & /@ {{1, 2}, {x, y}} == f @@@ {{1, 2}, {x, y}}`

Comment: Yes.. this is correct.. This is what O meant and using the purge function example help me see the picture. Also, I am assuming that "lst" is a typo?  do you mean "list" .... f@@@list  or this is just a short hand?